# Are Dynamics CRM 2011 webservices accessible from outside?

Tags: web-services

I am working on a CRM 2011 implementation and we need to give access to CRM webservices (for instance, the Update Account) methods.

This is because, our CRM needs to be feeded by *n* third party websites.

Can this be acomplished? Can the, original, native CRM webservices be opened to internet?

Note: We think, as an alternative, to wrap the original web service within a custom one, so, we expose our webservice, lets say "CreateAccount" and, from it call the local CRM webservice. But. this is a thing that we **really love to avoid.**

Comment: I don't know why this was moved from stackoverflow.  It has nothing to do with being a webmaster; it is a question about exposing an internal system with the outside world.

Comment: @JoshPainter and OP: I also don't agree with this decision. However, you could support the [Microsoft Dynamics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2) which would be the perfect place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable IFD (Internet-Facing Deployment) for your CRM system. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/crm/configuring-ifd-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011) is a link to get you started.